# Java autogenerated MySQL database connection encoding

Tags: java, mysql, encoding

i have a Java project connected to a MySQL database.
When I communicate between the two using executeQuery(query) everything seems to be fine with the encoding, BUT I have some autogenerated CRUD forms which throw exceptions when some encoding specific characters are used.
For eg. when I run 
`INSERT INTO db (id,name) VALUES (1,'ŠĐŽČĆšđžčć')`
from Java everything is ok, but when I update the database via the persistance entity manager autogenerated code sometimes i get an exception, sometimes i get some characters replaced by '?'. Note that SOME and not ALL characters are replaced.
So, how to set the encoding on the autogenerated code to work fine too?

TNX!

Comment: it's down in the anwser section...

Comment: but it is not an answer - edit your question and add it there. Then delete the answer.

Comment: yeah sorry, i know.. i just tought i would be easyer to read it formated..

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jsp add this on a page:

```
<%@ page language="java" pageEncoding="utf-8" contentType="text/html;charset=utf-8" %>
```

**EDIT:** I was misguided with CRUD forms but nevertheless I will leave it...

You can see Š, but you cant see  ć and č, right?
Try this:

set **character_set_server** variable to **utf8** if it is set to latin1

Answer (score 0):

Here's the persistance xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="kemoton_dbPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>oracle.toplink.essentials.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>...</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="toplink.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
      <property name="toplink.jdbc.password" value=""/>
      <property name="toplink.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/kemoton_db?characterEncoding=UTF-8"/>
      <property name="toplink.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

btw @ trix : it's a desktop app...